# jQuery Page Loader Problem

Tags: jquery, ajax, loader

I'm using the following code to load the pages dynamically with jQuery. The page loading works, but when you click the nav link to load a new page the old page flashes on the screen as if it's loading the previous page again. Click on the "Contact" nav link and see what I mean: http://ghostpool.com/wordpress/buzz. Why is this happening?

jQuery(document).ready(function() {

```
var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);
var href = jQuery('#nav li a').each(function(){
    var href = jQuery(this).attr('href');
    if(hash==href.substr(0,href.length-5)){
        var toLoad = hash+'.html #content';
        jQuery('#content').load(toLoad)
    }                                           
});

jQuery('#nav li a').click(function(){

    var toLoad = jQuery(this).attr('href')+' #content';
    jQuery('#content').hide('fast',loadContent);
    jQuery('#load').remove();
    jQuery('#page-wrapper').append('<span id="load">LOADING...</span>');
    jQuery('#load').fadeIn('normal');
    window.location.hash = jQuery(this).attr('href').substr(0,jQuery(this).attr('href').length-5);
    function loadContent() {
        jQuery('#content').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent())
    }
    function showNewContent() {
        jQuery('#content').show('normal',hideLoader());
    }
    function hideLoader() {
        jQuery('#load').fadeOut('normal');
    }
    return false;

});
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default behaviour is still running. you have to disable it using one of these ways:

```
jQuery('#nav li a').click(function(e){

e.preventDefault();

// or 

return false;// at the end of the function
}
```

EDIT:

After re-reading your code i see unusual stuff here wit your functions:

```
function loadContent() {
    jQuery('#content').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent())
}
function showNewContent() {
    jQuery('#content').show('normal',hideLoader());
}
```

instead of passing the callback functions you are passing the return value. here is how it should be

```
jQuery('#content').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent);
...
jQuery('#content').show('normal',hideLoader);
```

not the parentheses are removed

Comment: I've tried both solutions but neither are working. I guess I'm not inserting them into the code correctly. Code you show me how exactly these changes can be applied within the code I posted above? I should point out I already have return false at the end of the function.

Comment: @GhostPool, i havent noticed the return false at the end. anyway i spotted a mistake see my edit.